# How can i move adView through java code

Tags: android, admob

How can i move (on the screen) the adview from the file .java (using java code)? I can't move it through xml because i had troubles with admob jar using xml so i added the advertisment from my Main.java.

I tried a lot of methods like setGravity, setY, setX etc. but they all need API11 and i want my app to work on Gingerbread (API10). 
Now the adView is on the top of the screen. please help.

Comment: You are going to need to be way more specific in what you have and what you want. Start by posting the XML layout, and then explain where you want the ad to be displayed.

Comment: First of all, I can't add the adview through the xml because if I do so i get a null pointer exception (because of a problem in the admob sdk that will be fixed in the next major release). That's why I added the adview through java code. Now the ad is on the top of the screen but I'd like it to be "some pixels under"  a button or, at least,  at the bottom of the screen.  Unluckily i'm not at home and i can't post the xml,  however I can say that it is a relative layout and it is all about buttons,  editviews and textviews. In the xml there is nothing about the ad.

Answer (score 1):

You can create some `LayoutParams` and set the ad wherever you'd like if you're using a `RelativeLayout`. Here is how you could place the ad below a button with id `some_android_button_id`:

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.myrelativelayoutid);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams =
    new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.some_android_button_id);
layout.addView(adView, adParams);
```

Also note that you can still include your ad in XML. It unfortunately just breaks the WYSIWYG editor in Eclipse with v6.2.1 of the SDK - there are no exceptions in your actual app.